# How do i sort this with comparator?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I have arraylist with various objects "Equipo",
and i have to sort it in various sorting parameters

```
public class Equipo {

private String nombre;
private int puntos;
private int cantidadPartidosGanados;
private int golesDiferencia;
private int golesAnotados;
private int golesEnContra;
```

if int puntos; is equals sort by int cantidadPartidosGanados; if that is equals sort by int golesDiferencia; if that is equals sort by int golesAnotados; if that is equals sort by int golesEnContra; if that is equals sort by String nombre;

thank you very much!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should just be able to implement `Comparable<Equipo>` and provide the logic you've just outlined in your `compareTo()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, so you have to add this method to your class:

```
int compareTo(T o) {
    if (this.puntos > o.puntos)
        return 1;
    else if (this.puntos < o.puntos)
        return -1;
    else
        if (this.cantidadPartidosGanados > o.cantidadPartidosGanados)
            return 1;
        else if (this.cantidadPartidosGanados < o.cantidadPartidosGanados)
            return -1;
        else
          // and so on
}
```

Then call the [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) static method in Collections class and you'll get your list sorted.

Comment: what about in the last case? it is a name .. i cant ask for a <> sign
also how do i use this afterwards?

Comment: To compare strings you have to use this: `return this.nombre.compareTo(o.nombre)`

Answer (score 0):

To sort with a `Comparator`, supply an anonymous implementation to `Collections.sort()`:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Equipo>() {
    public int compare(Equipo a, Equipo b) {
        if (a.getPuntos() != b.getPuntos())
            return a.getPuntos() - b.getPuntos();
        if (a.getCantidadPartidosGanados() != b.getCantidadPartidosGanados())
            return a.getCantidadPartidosGanados() - b.getCantidadPartidosGanados();
        // etc for other attributes in order of preference, finishing with
        return a.getNombre().compareTo(b.getNombre());
    }
});
```

Comment: bohemian dont i have to ask if puntos is bigger or something_ why !=?? and why do you return the substraction of them?

Comment: As per the javadoc, the compare method should return a number less than zero if a is less than b, a number greater than zero is a is greater than b, and zero if they are equal. For rack attribute, you only want to compare them if they are *not* equal (hence the !=), and the comparison result is most simply expressed as the subtracting b from a (which obeys the contract).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other answers, I'm going for the educational approach so you can, at least, address the concepts you're applying.

Both `compareTo` (if you were to implement the `Comparable` interface) and a `Comparator` work based on the same principle. You return an int that is less than `0` when the first element is lower than the second, an int above `0` when the first element is higher than the second or `0` if they're equals.

`Comparator` provides an easy way to switch ordering criteria, allowing you to sort a collection in multiple ways based on the provided comparator.

Once yo define the `Comparator` object, you'll have to give a behaviour to `compare`, which returns an `int` according to the criteria I explained before. Given the precedence between fields in your `Equipo` class, your comparation must be done field by field, switching to the next one if they are equals. In pseudocode, it would look like this.

```
If equipo1.field1 != equipo2.field1
    compare the fields returning 1 or -1
Else
    If equipo1.field2 != equipo2.field2
        compare the fields returning 1 or -1
    Else
        ...
```

In the end, if all fields are equal, you'll have to return `0`.

Please note that when you're not working with primitive types (i.e. `String`), you can always use that object's own `compareTo` method. You'll know two objects are equal if their comparation returns `0`.

Comment: i implemented the whole thing but it just skips out of the method

Comment: @user2651401 what do you mean by skipping out? Care to show us your method? It might be missing some check and, thus, ending prematurely.